# Android build failed when using react-native-googlesignin

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react native googlesignin module.

When I run n android it throws error like this:
 [image: eror while running 'react-native run-android']

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
    dependencies {
compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
compile project(':react-native-android-permissions')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')

    compile project(':react-native-barcodescanner')
    compile project(':@remobile/react-native-splashscreen')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(":react-native-google-signin")

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1' // should be at least 9.0.0
      compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
}
```

I have tried the following also:

```
compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){         
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1' // should be at least 9.0.0
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried by clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: yes I tried but it did not solve my issue and it is  solved by changing the version for 9.2.1 to 10.2.1 as my other modules are using that version only thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`npm link` will search with regex, the current line is 
`compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){` so we need to change it to

```
compile project(":react-native-google-signin")
{         
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
}
```

and in this way, when `npm link` will detect the dependency and won't be duplicated